# ACL automation using python

Tags: python, automation, cisco

I've task for ACL statements rollout in pro devices. I'm learning the automation stuff and wanted to do this task using **Netmiko** module of Python.

So, now I need to increment seq-number and copy that output (ACL statement) into respective ACL.

For example, if I send a command:

```
sh ip access-lists vlan2_in | i 1.1.1.1
```

then the return value is

```
140 permit ip host 2.2.2.2 host 1.1.1.1
```

My code:

```
output = "140 permit ip host 2.2.2.2 host 1.1.1.1"
if "1.1.1.1" in output:
       ip_acl = output.replace("1.1.1.1","3.3.3.3")
       print(ip_acl)
```

Output of my code: `140 permit ip host 2.2.2.2 host 3.3.3.3`

In this way I've achieved the ACL statement with source intact. But, in output the ACL number (140) needs to be incremented by 1.

Expected output of my code: `141 permit ip host 2.2.2.2 host 3.3.3.3`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the ACL number from the command by using concept of slicing and then increment it by 1. To increment it you must convert it to int() and then replace it in the command.

```
output = "140 permit ip host 2.2.2.2 host 1.1.1.1"
ACL_NUMBER = output[:3]
if "1.1.1.1" in output:
    ip_acl = output.replace("1.1.1.1", "3.3.3.3")
    ip_acl = output.replace(ACL_NUMBER, str(int(ACL_NUMBER)+1))
print(ip_acl)
```